# Facing the issue of setting the origin

Tags: modeling, objects, geometry, origin, draw-mode

I hope, you all guys are having a good day. I am trying to make a rounded wall for well and to set its origin to the middle of the rounded wall. I have tried all the things from setting the origin to geometry and solely placing the origin point to the middle. But all in vain. edit: Its wireframe has been in the rounded form in all that struggle. I will be thankful if I get some help. It's blender 2.8 [image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect to see in the screenshot, but isn't the object just circled around the world's origin (where the 3D cursor is at the moment)? So did you try going to *Object Mode*, right-clicking the object, then in the context menu choose *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*?

EDIT: Or maybe it's not circling around the world origin. What about selecting the vertices that are furthest on X and -X as well as the ones furthest on Y and -Y. When they are selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, go to *Object Mode* and like suggested before, set origin to 3D Cursor?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to **Object Mode**, select your object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it, select the modifier and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply it, press <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> depending on settings to search for **origin to geometry (volume)** (or use the suggested method by Gordon, the furthest points), now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, cursor to selected, remove the duplicate, select the original, and now search for **origin to 3D cursor**.

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay attention... there is still a modifier on it, didn't see that when I answered.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to watch out for a hidden distinction, when using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to Selected, in Edit mode.

If the Transform Pivot Point is set to 'Bounding Box', that's where the cursor will go. If set to 'Median', the cursor will go the average location of the selected vertices. If the vertices are not evenly distributed, there is a difference:

[image]

If your outline is not too damaged, and the Cursor is at the Bounding Box center, then 'Origin to Cursor' should do the trick.

If you need to be very exact, the most precise method I've found is to use the shipped add-on 'TinyCAD', and its 'Resurrect Circle Center' operator. Select at least 3 vertices from your wall you know to be at a constant radius from the ideal center. The operator will then create a circle through those points, which you can use as your reference.